Using Advanced Formatting for the Indicator element in ArcGIS Dashboards to render a variable color to the Count number based on selected feature
In my Dashboard, the Indicator element displays the currently selected features (Statistic: Count) of a point layer. One of the fields in this layer, DISTRICT, contains the District value in which the point belongs. In my map view, each District is displayed as a polygon feature from a separate layer under the point layer and assigned a unique color in the map's symbology. I'm trying to use an Arcade expression in Advanced Formatting in Indicator Options to render the Indicator number, upon selection, the color of the feature as assigned in its DISTRICT field.
I have tried working with the Decode function to simplify the expression, for ex.:
var mtextcolor = Decode($feature.DISTRICT,
District 1, "#0070ff",
District 2, "#7eff50",
District 3, "#ff7f7f",
District 4, "#ffaa00",
"Unknown"
);

return {
  //textColor:'',
  //backgroundColor:'',
  //topText: '',
  //topTextColor: '',
  //topTextOutlineColor: '',
  //topTextMaxSize: 'medium',
  middleText: $datapoint.count_DISTRICT,
  middleTextColor: mtextcolor,
  middleTextOutlineColor: '',
  middleTextMaxSize: 'large',
  //bottomText: '',
  //bottomTextColor: '',
  //bottomTextOutlineColor: '',
  //bottomTextMaxSize: 'medium',
  //iconName:'',
  //iconAlign:'left',
  //iconColor:'',
  //iconOutlineColor:'',
  //noValue:false,
  //attributes: {
    // attribute1: '',
    // attribute2: ''
  // }
}


I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible, using the code method you are using. You have obvious set your Value Type to Statistic when constructing the indicator. The only profile variable that seems to be available is $datapoint so your code is invalid as you are trying to access $feature.
I would explore creating an indicator for each district and setting the Filter option to a particular district then count on that. In the example below I count on a field called quality control but that could easily be your district.

